# How to make MSBuild get the DCU output path from the DProj file?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a script that starts msbuild and compiles a bunch of libraries. Here is the **test** script for one of them:

```
CALL _whereIsDelphi.cmd Alex
CALL "%DelphiPath%\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild "c:\source\TOOLS\Lib1\Lib1.dproj" /t:Build /p:DCC_BuildAllUnits=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:platform=Win32
```

PS: In the end, I want to pass to the script the whole .ProjGroup file instead of just one .dropj file.

---

But I have a problem with the output folder. Even though the .dproj file is like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
<DCC_BplOutput>.\$(ProductVersion)\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_BplOutput>
<DCC_DcpOutput>.\$(ProductVersion)\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcpOutput>
<DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(ProductVersion)\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
```

the output (DCUs) goes to:

```
c:\source\TOOLS\Lib1\Win32\Release
```

instead of the expected:

```
c:\source\TOOLS\Lib1\22.0\Win32\Release
```

Any idea how to get the output (DCUs) to be created into the correct folder?

---

Note that even though most libraries are using the $(ProductVersion)$(Platform)$(Config) format for output, some of them don't. This is why I cannot use hard-coded output paths. I would really like to use the `$(ProductVersion)` because this way I can have the libraries for Delphi 10, 11, 12 running in parallel.

---

Update:

Experiments:

**DPROJ FILES**

1. In Project Options, I set the "unit output directory" to "Test" and the MS Build recognizes that.
2. Then I set it to `$(Config)\$(Config)` and it also works.
3. I also experimented to see if the MS Build can parse other fields from the DProj file. I experimented with the Map File (0 and 3) and it works.

Conclusion: the problem is only with the $(ProductVersion) variable, which is not recognized.

**SCRIPT**

1. In my script, I tried using `/p:DCC_DcuOutput="Test"`, and it works, but `/p:DCC_DcuOutput="$(ProductVersion)\$(Platform)\$(Config)"` will not work. It will not parse the `$()` variables. It will create the folders exactly as that: "$(ProductVersion)".
2. This will also not work: `/p:DCC_DcuOutput="$(ProductVersion)\ Error it:` Could not create output file '$\DebugForm.dcu'`

Conclusion: the problem is with all the $() variables. None is recognized.

HOWEVER, even if the script had been able to parse the $() vars, this solution will still not work with my ultimate goal: to pass to MS Build a ProjGroup file, because there is no more script involved there. The MS Build goes through the whole ProjGroup without in one go.

And I really don't want to compile via project group file and also via a script, because the two will get desynchronized at one point! Whatever change we do in the group will have to go to the script also.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I wanted the map file to generate regardless of how the project was configured. I discovered that I could do this:

**MSBuild.exe myproject.dproj /t:Build  /p:platform=Win64 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DCC_MapFile=3;DCC_Hints=false;DCC_Warnings=false**

where I specifically set these properties: **DCC_MapFile**, **DCC_Hints** and **DCC_Warnings** using the **/p** command line parameter.

I have not tried this, but perhaps you could do the same for **DCC_DcuOutput**.

Comment: Hi Steve. My problem is that I don't know in the script which is the output that I must use! The output path is in the DProj file. I guess I need to parse that file and extract the information from it.

Comment: Do you know how much is the MsBuild looking into the DProj file? Looks like it doesn't get much information from there! Embarcadero does not document much about this.

Comment: I agree that there is not much documentation surounding this whole area. Concerning the $() vars you need to set them as DOS environment variables before calling MsBuild. Also, the approach I have taken to project groups is to read the group file and then compile each project seperately. This best suits what we are doing.

Comment: I guess I have to live without the $(ProductVersion) variable since it is the one causing the problems...... At least until Emba will support it.

Comment: Would you post the script that is parsing the Project Group file? :)

Comment: I also experimented (see my updated question) to see if the MS Build could parse other fields from the DProj file. I experimented with the Map File (0 and 3) and it works. Why did you have a problem with that field? On which version have you tried it? Maybe it works now. :)

Comment: Hi IceCold. Unfortunately I cannot post the script as the code is pure Delphi which is proprietry (I am not the owner, just the developer) and also depends on internal libraries. Just so you understand, we use all of this for a web based build server entirely written in Delphi.

Comment: To be clear, I did not have a problem with the dproj file and map files. I just needed to override the project in this case via the msbuild command line to allow our build server to do "extra" stuff.